# Trying to find the largest value from the given data, per day and then try and map the largest data with date and time onto a graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table, spreadsheet

Scenario:

A machine is processing a number of items randomly throughout the day, every day i.e. 54x items are produced at 17:00 and then 207x items are processed at 18:00 etc (Screenshot provided)

My question:

In my pivot table how do I break the data down to show the maximum produced item per hour (not average) for that week to put in a column chart?

(Looking at the screenshot for that week I only want the 317 value at 10am captured) I would like to carry this on for the rest of the data that I have aswell, if possible!

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

[Image from excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ByWS.jpg)

Comment: Perhaps by building a helper table using sumif() to build your counts, and then max() to get the largest values. Then create a chart from that helper table.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple sample data, you just need to set the field to the maximum value according to the prompts in the screenshot：

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response!. I have a bigger workbook where the dates go back to 2019. When I group these dates for a 7 day period I'm trying to extract the largest value from an hourly input if that makes sense? Im trying to see what and when my maximum throughput/production was.

Comment: If you divide them into different time periods, I don't think pivot tables can do it.